# Exclude some directories while redirecting to https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2

I am loading every page over `https` using a rule as follows in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I need to redirect every page in the website to load over `https` protocol except some directories. I've tried using this rule

`RewriteRule ^dont-load-under-https-folder/ - [L,NC]`

But, it is still being applied to that `dont-load-under-https-folder`

Here is my whole htaccess code

```
IndexIgnore *

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^52\.76\.80\.144$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^http://52.76.80.144//(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^detector/ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^admin/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^b2b/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^config/ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^hub/ - [L,NC]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(\w+)\.php\?param=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]


## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

# handle ?param=...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param=$2 [L,QSA]



# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ending/thankyou(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /main\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^main\.html$ / [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^/?$ main.html [L]


# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
  \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/x-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot

  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 2 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 2 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 2 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 2 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 12 month"
  ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 12 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-ico "access plus 12 month"
  ExpiresByType application/ico "access plus 12 month"

ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 12 month"
ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 12 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 12 month"
ExpiresByType font/x-woff "access plus 12 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 12 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: from your question Its not clear what/where exactly the problem is. please post your full htaccess

Comment: @starkeen Check my htaccess code

Comment: Your rules are not in correct order. Put #Dont touch dirs rules before your https redirection rules.

Comment: @starkeen Exactly! Thank you for correcting

Answer (score 1):

This forces everything to `HTTPs` except for the directories that you specify within the brackets:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force everything to HTTPs
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#Checks if HTTPs is on for foobar & foobar2, if it is, turn it off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(foobar|foobar2)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can add as many directories as you like to this, just separate them with `|`. Replace `foobar` & `foobar2` etc with the directories you wish to exclude.